# InstallShield LE: Customizing uninstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uninstallation, installshield-le

I wrote a free utility that changes system settings.  Some users mistakenly think that they can undo the changes simply by uninstalling the utility.  When they try to uninstall, I want to show them a message telling them that they have to use the utility in order to undo the changes, and give them a choice of continuing or canceling the uninstall.  How do I do this?
I am using InstallShield LE with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is using an uninstall custom action. It can prompt the user and return 0 to continue or [1602](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cancel.

This custom action needs to be a win32 DLL which receives the installation handle. An EXE or .NET custom action can return only 0 for success or any other value for a fatal error (no user exit support).

Unfortunately InstallShield LE doesn't support DLL custom actions (it requires a paid version). So a solution is to use a different setup tool which offers more control over custom actions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Another solution is to manually add the custom action in your MSI by editing it with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How to build a custom DLL and then add it using Orca: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Comment: This has a little more information on writing a custom action DLL: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/

Comment: The CodeProject link talks about how the "message box can end up hidden behind the MSI dialogs".  This looks like a possible solution: http://geekswithblogs.net/Bretshawn/archive/2010/02/19/how-to-force-a-windows-installer-custom-action-form-to.aspx

Comment: Debugging the custom action: there are various relevant articles on the web; here is one: http://www.davidmoore.info/developedia/debugging/debugging-windows-installer-custom-actions-2/